# Как сделать кликабельные #хештеги и @упоминания в UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

Мне нужно внедрить кликабельные хештеги в UILabel. Условия следующие:
1. UILabel реализован через сториборд, а не программно (большинство библиотек на гитхабе используют свою реализацию UILabel программно и там задаётся заранее известные размеры)
2. Язык swift 2

Все примеры что я нашёл в гугле не удовлетворяют этим двум условиям. То язык не swift или третий свифт, то UILabel или TextView задаются не из сториборда, а программно. А у меня UI построен на автолайауте, причём это ячейки таблицы, с разной высотой.

Comment: найти бибилиотеку на свифте 3 и переписать на свифт 2?

Comment: Признаюсь честно, для меня это сложновато. Я пробовал одну переделать. Там после конвертации вылазит 30 ошибок.

Comment: а какой формат ответа вы ожидаете?

Comment: или вот такой вариант: найти библиотеку на swift3, и на гитхабе посмотреть комматы и найти когда она была сконвертированна в swift3, и взять один коммит до этого

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ну я думал может кто сталкивался с этим и подскажет библиотеку под swift 2. Но я уже нашёл выход, сам пишу метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как готовых решений удовлетворяющих полностью всем моим запросам не нашлось, то пришлось написать самому метод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кому-то пригодится.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TestTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var edittext: UITextView!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        TestTextView.attributedText = getColoredText(edittext.text)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Настраиваем распознавание нажатий
        TestTextView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.textViewTap(_:)))
        TestTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        //Раскрашиваем текст
        TestTextView.attributedText = getColoredText(TestTextView.text)
    }

    let hashtagCalloutColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 0.73, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1) //00BAA9

    func getColoredText(text:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
        let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

        //Находим все хештеги и упоминания и красим их в нужный цвет
        let pat = "[#]\\w+|[@]\\w+"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pat, options: [])
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(string.string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))

        //Здесь мы проходим по всем найденым словам и красим их
        if matches.count > 0 {
            for match in matches {
                string.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: hashtagCalloutColor, range: match.range)
            }
        }
        return string
    }

    func getWordForIndex(string string: String, index: Int) -> String {
        var startInd = index
        var endInd = 0
        let stringLngt = string.characters.count
        if stringLngt == index + 1 {endInd = index}
        else if stringLngt > index + 1 {
            endInd = index
            for i in index + 2 ... stringLngt {
                let x = i - 1
                let charctr = string[string.startIndex.advancedBy(x)]
                if charctr != " "  && charctr != "," && charctr != "\n" && i != stringLngt {endInd += 1}
                else {
                    endInd = x
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if index > 0 {
            for i in 1 ... index {
                let x = index - i
                let charctr = string[string.startIndex.advancedBy(x)]
                if charctr != " " && charctr != "\n" {startInd -= 1}
                else {break}
            }
        }

        if endInd < stringLngt - 1 {
        return string.substringWithRange(string.startIndex.advancedBy(startInd)..<string.startIndex.advancedBy(endInd))
        }
        else {
            return string.substringWithRange(string.startIndex.advancedBy(startInd)..<string.endIndex)
        }

    }

    func textViewTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let myTextView = gestureRecognizer.view as! UITextView
        let layoutManager = myTextView.layoutManager

        // location of tap in myTextView coordinates and taking the inset into account
        var location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(myTextView)   //.location(in: myTextView)
        location.x -= myTextView.textContainerInset.left
        location.y -= myTextView.textContainerInset.top

        // character index at tap location
        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: myTextView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        let word = getWordForIndex(string: myTextView.text, index: characterIndex)
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {
            print("hashtag = \(word)")
        }
        if word.hasPrefix("@") {
            print("mention = \(word)")
        }
    }

}
```